# Using colour keys on keypad from Chrome on Google TV

Tags: google-tv

I'm writing a Web app for Google TV and want to make use of the colour keys on the remote control for navigation. 
I'm not getting any input from the keys in response to onkeypress or onkeydown events, does anyone know if it is possible to use these keys for input in Web apps? I have seen the keys used in apps on Google TV but I suspect these may be Android apps. I can get input from the keyboard keys and the D controller without any difficulty.

Thanks in advance,
Gordon.

Comment: colour keys? can you attach a screenshot with those keys marked?

Answer (score 1):

The color key's are not currently supported within web applications. Chrome does not receive key events from the remote for the color keys.

Answer (score 0):

These color keys are designed for universal remote functionalities on TV.  Since there are no desktop equivalents to them, Chrome does not pass any keycode for them.

In general for available keys and keycodes, use the keycode tester here:

https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/implement_for_tv#keyboard